# WMI Task not working in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, wmi

I have an SSIS job that contains a WMI File Watcher task, which monitors a folder on another machine and processes files as they are placed in the folder.

This job, including the WMI File Watcher task, works perfectly in SSIS.  However, when the same package is executed through the SQL Server Agent it returns with a status of successful but does not process the file.

Is there anything that needs to be configured through the SQL Server to allow the WMI File Watcher task to see the incoming file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

**Misc. Details:**

- The package is setup with a protection level of EncryptSensitiveWithPassword
- The WMI File Watcher task has valid credentials with access to the remote machine
- The Server environment is: SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2
- The Remote Machine is running Windows XP

Comment: What is the account the SQL Agent is executing under? Are you accessing the share through a UNC path (\\server\share) or have you mapped a drive letter? Does the Agent Account have access to share? If driver letter, does the Agent account have that folder mapped (and with the same drive letter)?

Answer (score 0):

try running the sql server as administrator

start->sql server->right click->run as admin

Or

restart the sql server agent

run->services.msc->sql server agent->restart